# How to display the actual image onclick from gridview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the image in the chat box when I click on any of the images from the gridview however, whenever I try to do so it comes up with a text, so please advise what can be done to get the image itself instead of the text that is appearing, please help me out I've been stuck for too long

smiles_items_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/smile_image_view"
android:layout_width="45dp"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

BottomSheetDialog_Smiles.java

```
public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final int[] mThumbIds;
String[] mThumbIdsString = null;

public ImageAdapter2(Context c, int[] mThumbIds ,  String[] mThumbIdsString) 
{
 mContext = c;
 this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
 this.mThumbIdsString = mThumbIdsString;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length & mThumbIdsString.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public class Holder {
    ImageView img;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, 
ViewGroup parent) {

    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiles_items_layout, null);
    null);

    holder.img = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);
    holder.img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


    gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
        int i, long l) {
            JSONDictionary imageChat = new JSONDictionary();
            LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)view;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.getChildAt(0);
            imageView.getDrawable();
            imageChat.put("message", imageView);
            Communicator.getInstance().emit("new chat message", 
            imageChat);
        }
    });

    return grid;

    }

}
```

This is the result which appears when clicking on the image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Do you need an ImageView inside an image?

 I used this code to get an image. 
 Send your view this method get as image.

       protected Bitmap ConvertToBitmap(ImageView image_view) {
        Bitmap map;
        image_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        image_view.buildDrawingCache();
        return map=image_view.getDrawingCache();
    }

In ur adapter code


holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap b = ConvertToBitmap(holder.img);;
            //now get bitmap used to assign 
            imageChat.put("message", b);
            Communicator.getInstance().emit("new chat message",
                    imageChat);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162279/discussion-on-answer-by-bhuvaneshwaran-vellingiri-how-to-display-the-actual-imag).